# SharedPreferences with Intent putExtra

Tags: android-intent, sharedpreferences, android-studio-2.2

I just start learning android studio . i want to make a simple app when The user can put the name of place and at which day he want to visit that place .

I want to send the place name and day using intent putExtra to secondActivity( PLAN).
after that in secondActvity(PLAN) i want to use SharedPreferences so the place name and day can be saved. In case the user choose other place and day it can be added to the saved data.

here is my code   : 
DANAMALL(FirstActvity.java)

```js
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class DANAMALL extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG_PLACE = "keyplace";
    public static final String TAG_DAY = "keyDay";

    Button b1;
    EditText etpName;
    EditText etd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dana_mall);

        etpName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PLACE);
        etd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DAY);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DANAMALL.this, PLAN.class);
                intent.putExtra(TAG_PLACE, etpName.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(TAG_DAY, etd.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });}}
```

PLAN (secondActvity.java) :

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class PLAN extends Activity {
    TextView txt;
    Button b1;
    SharedPreferences plan ;
    public static final String TAG_PLACE = "keyplace";
    public static final String TAG_DAY = "keyDay";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.plan);

        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String place = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_PLACE );
        String Day = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_DAY);

                plan=getSharedPreferences("savekey",MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit=plan.edit();
                edit.putString("keyplace",place);
                edit.putString("keyday",Day);
                edit.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "YOUR PLAN SAVED :) ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                plan = getSharedPreferences("savekey", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String place = plan.getString("keyplace", "");
                String Day = plan.getString("keyday", "");

                String msg = "VISIT:" + place + "DAY :" + Day;
                b1.setText(msg);

            }
    }); }}
```

my problem : there is no data in secondActvity after passing it 
..... SharedPreferences not showing the saved data .

kindly i want to know how to fix this problem :)

Answer (score -2):

uses the intent putextra genre

String namestr=text a passer;

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,you_activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("code",namestr);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and to recover it on the other activity

```
String namestr = getIntent().getStringExtra("code");
```